# "Everything will be fine" vs "everything is going to be fine"

Tags: expression-choice

Example sentences:

> Everything will be fine as long as we are together.
>
> Everything is going to be fine as long as we are together.

Are both expressions the same? Or they have subtle differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When talking about the future, we can use will either going to.

**will** : to talk facts or things that we believe are true.
**going to** : is used with predictions.

Moreover, you may use **will** for making a **decision** and **going** to **after the decision has been made**. We sometimes also use the present continuous for planned events in the near future.

Coming back to your question: When we want to talk about future facts or things we believe to be true about the future, we use will. Therefore I would go with your first answer- Everything will be fine as long as we are together.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they're the same. 'Will be' and 'is going to be' almost define each other.

What doubts did you have?

Comment: I thought they had slightly different meanings.

Comment: Yes and that's what I was hoping you'd post… what difference did you think there was?

Comment: Maybe one focuses more on the present and the other on the future. And maybe one is more commonly used than the other.